Supabase Query Date Compare
Recently try to fetch data by comparing date (from flutter) to supabase which is form of (year, month, day) 2024-06-22 by this snippet =>
date = '2024-06-22'
 final res = await supabaseClient
          .from('user_routes')
          .select('*')
          .eq('route_from', routeFrom)
          .eq('route_to', routeTo)
          .gte('start_date', date)
          .lte('end_date', formatedDate);

but it gave me null hwo do i compare it from flutter to supabase.
I want those data to return that lie between date  i given
